# How does eclipse install apk files on devices? I get an parsing error when I do it manually

Tags: android, eclipse

When running my app from eclipse with my device plugged it, the app runs just fine. Everything seems perfect. So I decided to export and sign my app, then email the apk to myself via gmail. After downloading the apk on my device, I get an error saying "There is a problem parsing the package".

I have uninstalled all previous versions of the app, and authorized the phone to download apps outside of the google play store.

I was just wondering how eclipse was able to install the app on my phone fine.

Thanks.

Comment: May we know if you did this from command prompt or somewhere else?

Comment: @Rohodude Certainly. I ran the app by right clicking my project folder and selecting "Run as Android Application". I would then see from the Console that my app is being installed, followed by "Success!" and everything would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered why I was getting the "There is a problem parsing the package" error when trying to install the apk manually, and as ridiculous as it sounds, ***it was the fact that I renamed my apk after it was generated, that caused the error.***